# Make a chart based on CSV data, without changing the csv into excel

Tags: excel, csv, charts

I have a script which calculates some statisticst everyday, and writes one line to a .csv file.

I would like to have a chart in Excel which uses the data in the .csv, without me requiring to import the csv everytime.
Is this possible?

Note that I cannot write to an excel file from my script, only csv.
So I need some kind of "external source" in excel.

Comment: Have the chart in a different workbook and link to the data in the file, write the functions so it picks up all the data as it increments automatically...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a connection to the CSV file which can be displayed in a table, then you can generate a chart from that data. If you haven't worked with PowerQuery before, you can read more about it here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-an-excel-or-csv-file-power-query-fc377b2e-a742-4dea-8d7c-8e0f18c8e765